# Select > Upload FTP Solution for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ftp

in Netbeans, you can select a file on the project explorer and upload it directly to the ftp and it finds where to upload properly (amongst the folders and sub-folders,since the remote project is the copy of local project with the same folder, sub-folders and etc.) which provides quick solution when working on both local and remote.

I am wondering whether the same functionality is also available on Eclipse? I don't need anything complicated. This feature is what I only need. So if you know such plugin and how to use it, please enlighten me.

I am using Eclipse for PHP, my version of Eclipse is PDT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aptana Studio 3 (standalone or plugin) has [FTP download/upload functionality](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Create+a+FTP+Connection). And much more.

Comment: I am gonna try that but I didn't work with Eclipse PDT version tho.

Comment: Aptana Studio could be installed as a plugin into Eclipse or Eclipse PDT.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has a Build in FTP. Go Windows->Open Perspective ->Other->Remote System Explorer.Create New Connection . Right Click on Explorer->New Connection ->FTP.
Note:(For Eclipse Helios and above)